# zsh: how to autocomplete file names after python script name?

Tags: macos, autocomplete, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've just moved from bash to [zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh). It's a great terminal shell, but I'm missing one property - file name completion for non-standard executables.

For example, If ls gives `thread_pool_examples` and `thread_pools`:

[image]

Then typing `du`, space and <kbd>tab</kbd> would autocomplete the common prefix `thread_pool`, nd another click will iterate over the options:

[image]
[image]

Clicking <kbd>Enter</kbd> will pick the highlighted item.

The problem is that this does not work with my custom scripts. For example, if I run `rmf` - a Python executable in my path - and click tab, no autocomplete options will appear.

Any ideas how to make zsh autocomplete filenames for every executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, IMO something in your shell configuration is breaking things up. Try doing this to verify it:

```
zsh -f # starts a new shell ignoring your configuration
autoload compinit
compinit
./my-shell-script [TAB]
```

it completes with files. That is the default.

FWIW, if you want to bind a particular completer to a command/alias etc, you can do

```
compdef _jstack jstack

# simple _files completion
compdef _files my-local-python-script

# restrict to some file extensions
compdef '_files -g "*.(eps|ps|pdf)"' okular
```

Comment: Does not work. When I type `~/bin/rm` it autocompletes it to `~/bin/rmf`, but it does not autocomplete arguments.

Comment: I can assure you one thing: all those commands work in a vanilla zsh. Did you make the test with `zsh -f`? Does that work? If that works, you'll need to check your configuration. The most common cause of "zsh is not doing what it does by default" is oh-my-zsh getting funny. You may also try removing the completion cache, normally at `$ZDOTDIR/.zcompcache` and any `~/.zcompdump` (another source of funny completion problems).